# why some of my files get deleted when I git reset to a specific commit and I reset again to my original commit?

Tags: git

I'm learning `git reset` currently, and I decided to dig a little bit more. so, I checked out from my `head` which was attached to my `master` to some random commit which is `head~2` and from there I reseted to `head~200` (before I `reset` to anywhere I copied the master commit hash) and then I reset to my master.

so when I typed `git status`, I saw some of my files are deleted some other are modified and some other are untracked, then I typed `git diff head~200 head --name-only` to check the involved files, still some of the files in my git status weren't in git diff list, so I'm wondering what's goin on with my files and why they have changed when I reset to master?

[image]

git diff

[image]

git status

command I used for reseting: git reset "hash"

Comment: Can you share how you reset ?

Comment: just `git reset` without any option @Ôrel

Comment: reset does not mess up with the files as you have them in your working tree. It changes the `HEAD` pointer and the index (the way you are using it).... did you expect your files in the working tree to change with a reset?

Comment: Did you check `git help reset`? If you did, is there something that does not make sense in terms of what you are seeing as the output of your commands?

Comment: Also, could you switch those screenshots for text in the question?

Comment: I don't expect git reset to change my files, it is actually what `git reset` is doing and I don't know why It's  changing my file...and why should I turn my screenshots into text, does this action change anything?@eftshift0

Comment: if you want to distinguish three type git reset, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76239722/16142058) can help?

Comment: no,It didn't help @TheDarkKnight

Comment: you can check the answer @eftshift0

Comment: Yes, it does..... It can be indexed for searches whereas imag.... Whatever!

Answer (score 1):

> I don't expect git reset to change my files, it is actually what git reset is doing and I don't know why It's changing my file.

It doesn't change your files, it only shows what changes have become **out of index**.
I don't know which learning resources you use, but i would recommend you to check out Scott Chacon's great [article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified), demystifying git reset.

Yes, version of reset you used is `--mixed` (default one) mode of reset. This one preserves your working tree (aka sandbox, ie actual repo dir content), **but** it changes index entry (index for short) in order that entry to match that specified commit (HEAD~200 in your case). And because of `--mixed` mode **preserves** your working tree, those changes that were introduced after that specified commit, are preserved, but because of they are not part of the index now, at moment of resetting, they become untracked.

You can play now at this point, if you remove those untracked changes (via `git clean` command, designed for that), you are technically doing `--hard` reset, the most dangerous version of reset.

Personally i found several use cases where `git reset` is wholesome:

1. Squashing commits (via `--soft` option, as a preferred alternative for interactive rebase, because it doesn't mess with squash commit timestamp).
2. Doing rollbacks for specific subset of files (possibly huge subset, it can be oneliner, super convenient)
3. Rollback of messed up fresh merges (via `--hard` option, `git reset --hard HEAD^1`)
4. Rollback you current changes to last commited state (HEAD, `git reset --hard`). This command is not preferred now, because of there is modern alternative - `git restore`.

So, 1-2 use cases here i appreciate mostly, and recommend you to carefuly and patiently absorb the whole article, it will be paid off.

**UPDATE**

Well, reproduced your problem, but haven't answered to actual question - this is a side-effect of `checkout` command. Take a look of description of that command (git checkout --help):

> Updates files in the **working tree** to match the version in the index or the specified tree. If no pathspec was given, git checkout will also update HEAD to set the specified branch as the current branch.

So, checkout actually modifies actual repo content (git checkout HEAD~1  - if last commit introduced new file - that file will be removed, etc.).

After resetting back to your last commit, those content are already modified (removed or edited), git sees that actual content doesn't match to index, and marked those changes as untracked.

As a summary, `git checkout` is one whom to blame here.
If to make reset (without checkout) twice - back and forth - there will be no such problem.

Comment: this is not the correct answer....@Ryan

Comment: checkout the answer I just posted @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

when reseting to a specific commit, git before transferring the changes which we have in `git status`, does something else which is aligning the two commits:

in `--soft` when we want to transfer to the destination commit from our starting commit, it tries to change the files in the destination commit which it looks like to the starting commit, for instance if we have a file that exists in starting commit but not in the destination, it get added to the `index` as a untracked file and in a adverse scenario when a file exists in the destination but not in the starting commit, it just get deleted from the destination commit , and for files that exists in both commits but with different contents, git just overwrites the content of the existing file in the destination based of the content of that certain file in the starting commmit and of these changes get place in index when we use `--soft` and for the `--mixed` we have the same situation but changes are unstaged and for      `--hard` it just load the destination commit without any attempt for making our starting and destination commits similar.

for the scenario which we have changes in our `git status`, `git` first priority is to make changes based what I said above then it transfers the changes we have in our `git status`( and we all know how that works based on the documents)

Comment: `git before transferring the changes which we have in git status` - No, this is default `--mixed` option, which preserves working tree. I believe you haven't grasped the idea of reset yet.